# Select (column-name) as subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to have a SQL statement where the column names in the SELECT are a subquery. The basic format is:

```
SELECT (<subquery for columns>) FROM Table;
```

My subquery returns 4 rows of field names, so I need to make them a single row. I used:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(column_names::text),',') FROM Fieldnames;
```

And then I get a returned format of col1, col2, col3, col4 for my 4 returned rows as a string. If I paste in the raw test for my query, it works fine as:

```
SELECT (col1, col2, col3, col4) FROM Table;
```

The issue arises when I put the two together. I get an odd response from psql. I get a:

```
?column?
col1, col2, col3, col4
```

with no rows returned for:

```
SELECT(SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(column_names::text),',') FROM Fieldnames) FROM Table;
```

Conceptually, I think there are two ways I can address this. I need to get my subquery SELECT back in a format that I can put as the column-name argument to the first SELECT statement, but because I return multiple rows (of a single value of a varchar for the column name that I want), I thought I could just paste them together but I cannot. I am using psql so I do not have the "@" list trick.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Solution:
Here is why the question is not a duplicate, and how I solved it. In trying to simplify the question to be manageable, it lost its muster. I ended up writing a function because I couldn't use @ to pass a list to SELECT in PostgreSQL. When you want to select only a subset of rows, you cannot pass a nested (SELECT) even with an AS, although this works in Oracle. As a result, I wrote a function that effective created a string, and then passed it as the SELECT. There seems to be something fundamentally different on how the SQL parser in PostgreSQL handles the arguments for SELECT from Oracle, but everyone DB is different.

Comment: Rewrite the original question in instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Look into dynamic sql. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Comment: It's a complete different question from the previous "SQL column names and comparing them to row records in another table in PostgreSQL" because it gives a different issue.   "?column?" is the key here.  I have no idea why that is being generated

Comment: You're doing this in `psql` and you're getting a `?column?` header in the output? That's probably just `psql`'s placeholder for a column in the result that has no specific name, throw a column alias in and you'll get the alias as a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enclose several column names in parentheses like you do:

```
SELECT (col1, col2, col3, col4) FROM tbl;
```

.. you effectively create an ad-hoc [**row type**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) from the enclosed columns, which has no name, because you did not provide an alias. Postgres will choose a fallback like `?column?`. In later Postgres versions the default name is `row` since, internally, the above is short syntax for:

```
SELECT ROW(col1, col2, col3, col4) FROM tbl;
```

Provide your own name (alias):

```
SELECT (col1, col2, col3, col4) AS my_row_type FROM tbl;
```

But you probably just want individual columns. Drop the parentheses:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM tbl;
```